# Update column data according to Another column on the same table in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, append

My table looks like this right now (A sample that required for my question):

Name of table : `JurnalEntries.dbo`

```
JE_InsertDate  JE_OriginalFileName

2015-04-01              NULL 
2015-04-01              NULL
2015-03-01              NULL
2015-03-01              NULL
2015-02-01              NULL
2015-02-01              NULL
```

And I want to insert values in the `JE_OriginalFileName` according to the `JE_InsertDate` (Date type). For example:

If value in `JE_InsertDate` is  `2015-02-01` then put in `JE_OriginalFileName` on the same row as  `FI 02 2015.xlsx`

If value in `JE_InsertDate` is  `2015-03-01` than put in `JE_OriginalFileName` on the same row as  `FI 03 2015.xlsx`

The table needs to look like this:

```
JE_InsertDate  JE_OriginalFileName

2015-04-01              FI 04 2015.xlsx 
2015-04-01              FI 04 2015.xlsx
2015-03-01              FI 03 2015.xlsx
2015-03-01              FI 03 2015.xlsx
2015-02-01              FI 02 2015.xlsx
2015-02-01              FI 02 2015.xlsx
```

Can you please help me right a query for this?

> Comment: There are spaces in the file name[(FI MM YYYY).xlsx].

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with CONCAT()

```
UPDATE JurnalEntries.dbo
SET JE_OriginalFileName = CONCAT('FI ', MONTH(JE_InsertDate),' ', YEAR(JE_InsertDate),'.xlsx')
```

if JE_InsertDate is a date, else use SUBSTRING instead of YEAR() and MONTH()

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CASE with update.

```
UPDATE JurnalEntries.dbo
    SET JE_OriginalFileName = CASE
    WHEN JE_InsertDate='2015-02-01' THEN 'FI 02 2015.xlsx'
    WHEN JE_InsertDate='2015-03-01' THEN 'FI 03 2015.xlsx'
    END
```

Hope this helps..